# Why do components not appear in my JComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jcomponent

I created a class that extends `JComponent`.  An object of that class is added to a `JPanel`.  A `JPanel` has a default flow layout manager.  When I added the `JPanel` to a `JFrame`, nothing was visible except an empty `JFrame`. Yes, the frame is visible and sized to the maximum screen dimensions.

I tried several modifications to change this problem and deduced:

- Component size - set it to no avail and still an empty `JFrame`
- Intermediate panel - adding component to an intermediate panel and still an empty `JFrame`

Finally I decided to change the layout manager of the panel I was adding my component to and changed the panel layout manager to a border layout.  I then added the component to the center and now it appears.

Follow-on questions I have are:

- When making a custom `JComponent`, what are my considerations?
- Why do I have to change the layout manager of a panel for a custom `JComponent`?

My naivety asks "If I can add a `JButton` to a panel and, using the default flow layout manager it shows, why not a custom `JComponent`?

My custom `JComponent` is an inner class:

```
public class OuterClass
{
     private class Panel extends JPanel
     {
           public Panel()
           {
                add(new Custom());
           }
     }

     private class Custom extends JComponent
     {
          public Custom()
          {
             // Initialization of members but not size of component
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This doesn't say much without any components

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Laying out Components in a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A JPanel has a default flow layout manager.

Yes, and the FlowLayout respects the preferred size of every component. Your component doesn't have a preferred size so it defaults to (0, 0).

Override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the appropriate dimension.

Comment: If I set the size, it appears to be ignored by the layout manager and only a preferred size is respected.  Why is that?

Comment: @Mushy, that is the way layout managers work. The job of the layout manager is to set the size and location of a component. Read the tutorial that was linked to in the comments under your question.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Why do I have to change the layout manager of a panel for a custom JComponent?"*

The thing about `JComponent` is that it has no default `LayoutManager` to layout the components. If you run this test, you'll see

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JComponent component = new JComponent() {};
    System.out.println("JComponent = " + component.getLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    System.out.println("JPanel = " + panel.getLayout());
}
```

The result is

```
JComponent = null
JPanel = java.awt.FlowLayout[hgap=5,vgap=5,align=center]
```

So with `JComponent`, since it has a `null` layout, it doesn't know where to layout the the component. So you either have to

- Explicity `setBounds()` on the component you want to add, or
- Explicity set the layout, like you mentioned you had to do for the `JComponent`.

> *"Finally I decided to change the layout manager of the panel I was adding my component to and changed the panel layout manager to a border layout. I then added the component to the center and now it appears."*
>   
>   So by setting the `LayoutManager` to `BorderLayout`, you told the `JComponent` how to layout the components you add. It can be *any* `LayoutManager` though, not just `BorderLayout`